# How To Subtract two times

Tags: vb.net

**Hi guys**

i searched so much for this but no result  so i need help!!

I have two times those are in this form ("hh:mm")

like this ex:

15:20 - 12:10 = 03:10

but in other form of variables because the times are not static and saved in SQL DB

i don't know what variable those should be string or dateandtime

```
a = dr!t_in
b = dr!t_out
msgbox(a-b) 'this shows the answer
```

many tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using the `TimeSpan` class.

```
Dim timeIn As String = "12:10"
Dim timeOut As String = "15:20"
MessageBox.Show(TimeSpan.Parse(timeOut).Subtract(TimeSpan.Parse(timeIn)).ToString(("hh\:mm")))
```

Comment: tanks man it worked just fine but the result is like "03:10:00" how to get ride of 00 at the end of it to be like "03:10"

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [DateTime object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx), and specifically the [Subtraction operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2(v=vs.110).aspx). You'll have to convert the times into DateTime objects first, which is fairly straightforward.